# How do I start multiple terminals inside NeoVim with one command?

Tags: gulp, vagrant, neovim

Currently I'm using Vim in combination with Cmder/ConEmu on Windows.

My Cmder has "tasks" that I run to start a group of terminals, where one starts with Vim in the correct folder, one with Gulp and one with Vagrant.

Now that you can start terminals in NeoVim, I would like to make a simple script that starts the same terminals, except inside NeoVim.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's very simple. Just use a vim macro.. :)

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros